# EOFException thrown on BlackBerry when trying to open TLS connection with Connector.open()

Tags: blackberry, connection, ssl, eofexception

Sometimes I get `EOFException` when I try to open a TLS connection over Wi-Fi with

```
Connector.open("tls://sub.domain.com:443;deviceside=true;interface=wifi;EndToEndRequired");
```

The call to `Connector.open()` is blocking. The `EOFException` is thrown about 10 seconds after the call to Connector.open(). Currently, I am unable to check what happens on the server side.

**Edit:**
The call to Connector.open() is made from a thread that is NOT the main event thread. The problem appears on various devices that run OS 6, though I don't think the problem is OS specific.

Any thoughts on how to solve this or what can be causing the error?

**Update**:
At some occasions, the call to Connector.open() also *yields* a `TLSAlertException` wrapped inside `TLSIOException`. The exception is not thrown immediately, but rather after about 10 seconds as previously mentioned `EOFException`.

Comment: Two questions: 1) are you sure the exception is being thrown by Connector.open() ? 2) are you calling Connector.open() on a separate thread from the OS event thread?

Comment: Yes, the exception is thrown by Connector.open() and yes, it is called from a different thread (not main event thread).

Comment: Unless there is something diagnostic in the exception message (unfortunately unlikely) or stack trace I would suspect the server is throwing up something the BlackBerry doesn't expect. Maybe set up a server that you can examine, or if it makes sense in the context of the rest of the code try a site with a known good server. I've used this kind of connection to talk to a secure webserver but normally use https protocol.

Comment: @Richard Unfortunately there is nothing diagnostic (`null` for exception message). I agree with you that the server is probably throwing something (maybe something goes wrong during the TLS handshake). Nothing much to do with it on BlackBerry side. Thanks you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to capture the TLS handshake on the server side and I saw the following:

1. Server received the **Client Hello** message
2. Server responded with **Server Hello** message
3. **Client key exchange** was not received from the client for about 10 seconds
4. Server closed the connection with the client

Since I see no way to influence on the `Connector.open()` flow, the only thing I can do is retry (I never saw it happening twice in a row) after `catch`ing either `EOFException` or `TLSAlertException` (and possibly other TLS related exceptions).